# Force render the block programmatically?

Tags: blocks, theming

Is it possible? For example, if the module's block meets your needs but it a block (not a page) and you want to use ready solution. Writing in a tpl.php file something like `render(desired_block)`, i.e. to get an output markup of the block for reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version of Drupal you are using but here is how I rendered a block in drupal 7.

```
<?php 
  $block = block_load('MODULE_NAME', 'DELTA'); 
  $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
  print $output; 
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you mark it as the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: There's a minimum time limit for marking an answer=) Don't worry.